# Cannot remove padding in table

Tags: html, css, padding

I am trying to remove the padding from the cells inside my table. I have set it to not have padding in the relevant CSS selectors but not a success.

As you can see, there is padding on all of these cells. 
[image]

I would like there to not be. I have tried various different padding settings and changing the vertical alignment makes no difference other than to move the text, the padding just goes from all at the bottom to spread between bottom and top.

Below is the code:

```js
'use strict'
let table = document.getElementById("mainTable")
let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")
let columns = table.querySelectorAll("#weeks th")

for (let row of rows) {
  for (let o = 0; o<columns.length-1; o++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("td")
    cell.innerHTML='&nbsp'


    cell.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]) { return } //If cell currently has an input box
      //
      let oldValue = ""
      if (cell.innerHTML !== "&nbsp;") { //if cell has a saved value
        oldValue = cell.innerHTML
      }
      cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="cellInputs">'

      //update input box with old value and focus it
      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus()
      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = oldValue

      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          cell.innerHTML=cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
          e.preventDefault()
          return true
        }
      })
      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        console.log(e)
        let cellValue = cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        if (e.data === "." && (cellValue.split('.').length-1 > 1 || cellValue === ".")) {
          console.log("stop")
          cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = (cellValue).substring(0, cellValue.length - e.data.length)
        }
        if (isNaN(e.data) && e.data !==".") {
          console.log("Stop")
          cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = (cellValue).substring(0, cellValue.length - e.data.length)
        }

        //store value inputted into the actual cell
      })
      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
   //      clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
   // pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

        let cellValue = cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        if (cellValue !== "") {
          e.preventDefault()
          return false
        }
        if (e.clipboardData.getData('text') === "." && (cellValue.split('.').length-1 > 1 || cellValue === ".")) {
          e.preventDefault()
          return false
        }
        if (isNaN(e.clipboardData.getData('text')) && e.clipboardData.getData('text') !==".") {
          e.preventDefault()
          return false
        }

        //store value inputted into the actual cell
      })
      cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("focusout", function() {
        console.log(document.activeElement)
        cell.innerHTML=cell.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
      })
    })


    row.appendChild(cell)
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Times, serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html{
  background-color: #35454E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html *{
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: white !important;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  color:#35454E;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
table, th{
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding:0;
}
th{
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
td{
  vertical-align:top;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    padding:0;
}
.cellInputs{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border:none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #35454E;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MMS.css">
  <title>Money Management</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mainTable"> 
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>2019</th>
        <th colspan="5">January</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="weeks">
        <th>&nbsp</th>
        <th>31/12/2018</th>
        <th>07/01/2019</th>
        <th>14/01/2019</th>
        <th>21/01/2019</th>
        <th>28/01/2019</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pay</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rent</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="MMS.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: i ran the snippet and there is no such padding

Comment: @SirDad  think the javascript isn't running properly on the snippet for some reason. So its not adding the data cells

Comment: Your example does not have the problem you describe. Voting to close.

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: @Dean your javascript was not running because the loop `for(let o =0;o<columns.length-1:o++)` wasn't looping because `comluns` was `undefined` because the id in the `querySelector` was  `#week th` not `#Week th`

Comment: @SirDad Ah thank you, didn't realize it was case sensitive. Didn't have that issue locally.Fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` from table .

Comment: That does solve the problem however, how would I make the table be the height of the screen? Without the padding issue, as that's what I need it to do. Thank you for the answer

Comment: you cannot do that